# Compute Normals After Vertex Deformation?

Tags: glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I am coding a vertex and a fragment shader trying to distort the surface of some water and then computing blinn-phong lighting on the surface. I am able to successfully compute the deformed matrices with a simple noise function, but how can I find the distorted normals? Since it isn't a linear transformation I am stuck, could anyone help?

Here are the relevant files:

vertex shader:

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 u_Model;  

uniform mat4 u_ModelInvTr;

uniform mat4 u_ViewProj;

uniform vec4 u_Color;       
uniform int u_Time;

in vec4 vs_Pos;             // The array of vertex positions passed to the shader

in vec4 vs_Nor;             // The array of vertex normals passed to the shader

in vec4 vs_Col;             // The array of vertex colors passed to the shader.

in vec2 vs_UV;              // UV coords for texture to pass thru to fragment shader

in float vs_Anim;           // 0.f or 1.f To pass thru to fragment shader
in float vs_T2O;

out vec4 fs_Pos;
out vec4 fs_Nor;           
out vec4 fs_LightVec;       
out vec4 fs_Col;           
out vec2 fs_UVs;
out float fs_Anim;
out float fs_dimVal;
out float fs_T2O;

uniform vec4 u_CamPos;
out vec4 fs_CamPos;

const vec4 lightDir = normalize(vec4(0.0, 1.f, 0.0, 0));

mat4 rotationMatrix(vec3 axis, float angle) {
    axis = normalize(axis);
    float s = sin(angle);
    float c = cos(angle);
    float oc = 1.0 - c;

    return mat4(oc * axis.x * axis.x + c, oc * axis.x * axis.y - axis.z * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.x + axis.y * s, 0.0, oc * axis.x * axis.y + axis.z * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.y + c,           oc * axis.y * axis.z - axis.x * s,  0.0,oc * axis.z * axis.x - axis.y * s,  oc * axis.y * axis.z + axis.x * s,  oc * axis.z * axis.z + c, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

vec4 rotateLightVec(float deg, vec4 LV) {

    mat4 R = rotationMatrix(vec3(0,0,1), deg);
    return R * LV;
}

float random1(vec3 p) {
    return fract(sin(dot(p, vec3(127.1, 311.7, 191.999)))*43758.5453);
}

vec3 random2( vec3 p ) {
    return fract( sin( vec3(dot(p, vec3(127.1, 311.7, 58.24)), dot(p, vec3(269.5, 183.3, 657.3)), dot(p, vec3(420.69, 69.420, 469.20))) ) * 43758.5453);
}

void main()
{
    fs_Col = vs_Col; 
    fs_UVs = vs_UV;
    fs_Anim = vs_Anim;
    fs_T2O = vs_T2O;

    mat3 invTranspose = mat3(u_ModelInvTr);
    fs_Nor = vec4(invTranspose * vec3(vs_Nor), 0); 

    vec4 modelposition = u_Model * vs_Pos; 

    if (vs_Anim != 0) { // if we want to animate this surface
        // check region in texture to decide which animatable type is drawn
        bool lava = fs_UVs.x >= 13.f/16.f && fs_UVs.y < 2.f/16.f;
        bool water = !lava && fs_UVs.x >= 13.f/16.f && fs_UVs.y <= 4.f/16.f;

        if (water) {
            // define an oscillating time so that model can transition back and forth
            float t = (cos(u_Time * 0.05) + 1)/2; // u_Time increments by 1 every frame. Domain [0,1]
            vec3 temp = random2(vec3(modelposition.x, modelposition.y, modelposition.z)); // range [0, 1]
            temp = (temp - 0.5)/25; // [0, 1/scalar]
            modelposition.x = mix(modelposition.x - temp.x, modelposition.x + temp.x, t);
            modelposition.y = mix(modelposition.y - temp.y, modelposition.y + 3*temp.y, t);
            modelposition.z = mix(modelposition.z - temp.z, modelposition.z + temp.z, t);

        } else if (lava) {
            // define an oscillating time so that model can transition back and forth
            float t = (cos(u_Time * 0.01) + 1)/2; // u_Time increments by 1 every frame. Domain [0,1]
            vec3 temp = random2(vec3(modelposition.x, modelposition.y, modelposition.z)); // range [0, 1]
            temp = (temp - 0.5)/25; // [0, 1/scalar]
            modelposition.x = mix(modelposition.x - temp.x, modelposition.x + temp.x, t);
            modelposition.y = mix(modelposition.y - temp.y, modelposition.y + 3*temp.y, t);
            modelposition.z = mix(modelposition.z - temp.z, modelposition.z + temp.z, t);
        }
    }

    fs_dimVal = random1(modelposition.xyz/100.f);


    fs_LightVec = rotateLightVec(0.001 * u_Time, lightDir);  // Compute the direction in which the light source lies

    fs_CamPos = u_CamPos; // uniform handle for the camera position instead of the inverse
    fs_Pos = modelposition;

    gl_Position = u_ViewProj * modelposition;// gl_Position is a built-in variable of OpenGL which is
                                             // used to render the final positions of the geometry's vertices

}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform vec4 u_Color; // The color with which to render this instance of geometry.
uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
uniform int u_Time;
uniform mat4 u_ViewProj;
uniform mat4 u_Model;

in vec4 fs_Pos;
in vec4 fs_Nor;
in vec4 fs_LightVec;
in vec4 fs_Col;
in vec2 fs_UVs;
in float fs_Anim;
in float fs_T2O;

in float fs_dimVal;

out vec4 out_Col;

in vec4 fs_CamPos;

float random1(vec3 p) {
    return fract(sin(dot(p,vec3(127.1, 311.7, 191.999)))
                 *43758.5453);
}

float random1b(vec3 p) {
    return fract(sin(dot(p,vec3(169.1, 355.7, 195.999)))
                 *95751.5453);
}

float mySmoothStep(float a, float b, float t) {
    t = smoothstep(0, 1, t);
    return mix(a, b, t);
}

float cubicTriMix(vec3 p) {
    vec3 pFract = fract(p);
    float llb = random1(floor(p) + vec3(0,0,0));
    float lrb = random1(floor(p) + vec3(1,0,0));
    float ulb = random1(floor(p) + vec3(0,1,0));
    float urb = random1(floor(p) + vec3(1,1,0));

    float llf = random1(floor(p) + vec3(0,0,1));
    float lrf = random1(floor(p) + vec3(1,0,1));
    float ulf = random1(floor(p) + vec3(0,1,1));
    float urf = random1(floor(p) + vec3(1,1,1));

    float mixLoBack = mySmoothStep(llb, lrb, pFract.x);
    float mixHiBack = mySmoothStep(ulb, urb, pFract.x);
    float mixLoFront = mySmoothStep(llf, lrf, pFract.x);
    float mixHiFront = mySmoothStep(ulf, urf, pFract.x);

    float mixLo = mySmoothStep(mixLoBack, mixLoFront, pFract.z);
    float mixHi = mySmoothStep(mixHiBack, mixHiFront, pFract.z);

    return mySmoothStep(mixLo, mixHi, pFract.y);
}

float fbm(vec3 p) {
    float amp = 0.5;
    float freq = 4.0;
    float sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        sum += cubicTriMix(p * freq) * amp;
        amp *= 0.5;
        freq *= 2.0;
    }
    return sum;
}

void main()
{
    vec4 diffuseColor = texture(textureSampler, fs_UVs);

    bool apply_lambert = true;

    float specularIntensity = 0;

    if (fs_Anim != 0) {
        // check region in texture to decide which animatable type is drawn
        bool lava = fs_UVs.x >= 13.f/16.f && fs_UVs.y < 2.f/16.f;
        bool water = !lava && fs_UVs.x >= 13.f/16.f && fs_UVs.y < 4.f/16.f;

        if (lava) {
            // slowly gyrate texture and lighten and darken with random dimVal from vert shader
            vec2 movingUVs = vec2(fs_UVs.x + fs_Anim * 0.065/16 * sin(0.01*u_Time),
                                  fs_UVs.y - fs_Anim * 0.065/16 * sin(0.01*u_Time + 3.14159/2));
            diffuseColor = texture(textureSampler, movingUVs);
            vec4 warmerColor = diffuseColor + vec4(0.3, 0.3, 0, 0);
            vec4 coolerColor = diffuseColor - vec4(0.1, 0.1, 0, 0);
            diffuseColor = mix(warmerColor, coolerColor, 0.5 + fs_dimVal * 0.65*sin(0.02*u_Time));

            apply_lambert = false;

        } else if (water) {
            // blend between 3 different points in texture to create a wavy subtle change over time
            vec2 offsetUVs = vec2(fs_UVs.x - 0.5f/16.f, fs_UVs.y - 0.5f/16.f);
            diffuseColor = texture(textureSampler, fs_UVs);
            vec4 altColor = texture(textureSampler, offsetUVs);

            altColor.x += fs_dimVal * pow(altColor.x+.15, 5);
            altColor.y += fs_dimVal * pow(altColor.y+.15, 5);
            altColor.z += 0.5 * fs_dimVal * pow(altColor.z+.15, 5);

            diffuseColor = mix(diffuseColor, altColor, 0.5 + 0.35*sin(0.05*u_Time));
            offsetUVs -= 0.25f/16.f;
            vec4 newColor = texture(textureSampler, offsetUVs);
            diffuseColor = mix(diffuseColor, newColor, 0.5 + 0.5*sin(0.025*u_Time)) + fs_dimVal * vec4(0.025);
            diffuseColor.a = 0.7;

            // ----------------------------------------------------
            // Blinn-Phong Shading
            // ----------------------------------------------------
            vec4 lightDir = normalize(fs_LightVec - fs_Pos);
            vec4 viewDir = normalize(fs_CamPos - fs_Pos);
            vec4 halfVec = normalize(lightDir + viewDir);
            float shininess = 400.f;
            float specularIntensity = max(pow(dot(halfVec, normalize(fs_Nor)), shininess), 0);
        }
    }

    // Calculate the diffuse term for Lambert shading
    float diffuseTerm = dot(normalize(fs_Nor), normalize(fs_LightVec));

    // Avoid negative lighting values
    diffuseTerm = clamp(diffuseTerm, 0, 1);

    float ambientTerm = 0.3;

    float lightIntensity = diffuseTerm + ambientTerm;   //Add a small float value to the color multiplier
                                                        //to simulate ambient lighting. This ensures that faces that are not
                                                        //lit by our point light are not completely black.

    vec3 col = diffuseColor.rgb;

    // Compute final shaded color
    if (apply_lambert) {
        col = col * lightIntensity + col * specularIntensity;
    }

    // & Check the rare, special case where we draw face between two diff transparent blocks as opaque
    if (fs_T2O != 0) {
        out_Col = vec4(col, 1.f);
    } else {
        out_Col = vec4(col, diffuseColor.a);
    }

    // distance fog!
    vec4 fogColor = vec4(0.6, 0.75, 0.9, 1.0);
    float FC = gl_FragCoord.z / gl_FragCoord.w / 124.f;
    float falloff = clamp(1.05 - exp(-1.05f * (FC - 0.9f)), 0.f, 1.f);
    out_Col = mix(out_Col, fogColor, falloff);
}
```

I tried implementing blinn-phong in the fragment shader, but I think it is wrong simple from the wrong normals. I think this can be done with some sort of tangent and cross product solution, but how can I know the tangent of the surface given we only know the vertex position?

I am not using unity, just bare c++ and most of the answers I am finding online are for java or unity which I do not understand.`